# How to make pages show up at the Calendar Nav calendar?

Tags: concrete5

I am trying to set up a website with [Calendar Nav](https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/calendar-nav/).

I have installed the add-on. Adding the calendar block works just fine.

[image: The calendar block works]

However, I fail to get the pages I want displayed at the calendar.

[image: The blog posts I am trying to display in the calendar]

[The demo site gets those pages at the calendar, but I don't.](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e514w3bec)

**What have I tried:**

I have, of course, read the [instructions](http://www.surefyre.com/news/calendar-nav-addon-released/) and tried to follow them up. (I've also searched the web for instructions etc.) I must have done something wrong though…

1. [The pages I want to displayed do have the "Show this item in Calendar Nav" setting enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szgso.png)
2. I have added a Calendar Nav block set to "List" mode (both at the blog and the home page), pointing to the blog.

I suspect I did something wrong with the list mode, though. Nothing shows where I place it.

How can I make the blog posts show up in the calendar?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of this addon? Click the "Support" link in the sidebar of its marketplace page.

Comment: It looks like I’ve gotten it to work now, but I’m not sure what caused it not to work in the first place. I suspect that it has something to do with the document still being in draft mode.